# How to solve this cubic equation? $x^3 -3x^2+ 4 = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I am having trouble solving this cubic equation. It seems that none of the tricks I learned before are working.

> Find all values of $x$:
>   $$x^3 -3x^2+ 4 = 0 $$

Comment: What if $$x=-1?$$

Comment: How do I even start? Is it based off of guess and check?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: also  $$x^3-3x^2+4=x^3+1-3(x^2-1)$$

Comment: "Where do I even start?"  Rational root theorem.  Remember this.  If a textbook expects you to factor a polynomial of degree ${}\ge 3$, then usually it has one or more rational roots.

Comment: There are general ways of approaching factoring a cubic.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc) provided a great explanation that I thoroughly enjoyed, making me agree with the creator that not teaching the cubic formula in schools for so long has probably been a great disservice since the technique in deriving the formula seems so useful.  That said, I can understand not teaching it on the grounds that factoring cubics is not something that comes up regularly in physics and geometric applications.

Comment: $x^3-3x^2+4 = (x-a)(x^2+bx+c) = 0$. What is the value of $a$? Having found that, can you find $b$ and $c$?

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the rational root theorem that *if* the equation has a rational root, then it must be one of the numbers $\pm1$, $\pm2$ or $\pm4$. And it is easy to see that $2$ is indeed a root. Can you take it from here?

Comment: It would be (x-2)^2 right. As for the third solution, is it just based on guess and check?

Comment: No. Since $2$ is a root, you can divide $x^3-4x^2+4$ by $x-2$; you will get $x^2-x-2$. Now, find the roots of this quadratic polynomial.